# What is the agent noun for verbs ending in -y?

Tags: nouns, suffixes

What is the correct way of spelling it, and what would the rule be for -y verbs like retry.

Is it retryer or retrier?

That is, on -y verbs, is the y kept or substituted by i?

Comment: I really don't know in what context one would use tryer and retryer to refer to any agent.

Comment: Software engineering, for example. Naming things is hard, questions like these often come up.

Answer (score 4):

The normal rule is: If you add "-er" to a word that ends in "y", then if the letter before the "y" is a consonant, change the "y" to an "i" before adding the "er". If the preceding letter is a vowel, leave the "y" as is.

Thus, try -> trier and amplify -> amplifier, but assay -> assayer and buy -> buyer.

There are probably exceptions. English has exceptions to almost every rule. :-( But off the top of my head I can't think of one.

Comment: **Flyer** occurred to me. But then so did **flier**

Comment: **Fryer** is an exception, although the alternate spelling **frier** is sometimes used.

Comment: Also **dryer**. Some dictionaries allow **drier**, but it's rare. For the adjective, though, the opposite is true (of this word).